# Execute curl requests in parallel in bash

Tags: curl, wget, multi-core, smp

What is the best way to execute 5 `curl` requests in `parallel` from a bash script? I can't run them in serial for performance reasons.

Comment: Have you tried searching for parts of your solution? Another SF question seems to be exactly what you're asking for: http://serverfault.com/questions/248143/multithreaded-downloading-with-shell-script

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634109/parallel-download-using-curl-command-line-utility

Answer (score 33):

Use '&' after a command to background a process, and 'wait' to wait for them to finish. Use '()' around the commands if you need to create a sub-shell.

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -s -o foo http://example.com/file1 && echo "done1" &
curl -s -o bar http://example.com/file2 && echo "done2" & 
curl -s -o baz http://example.com/file3 && echo "done3" &

wait
```

Comment: Simple, but effective for a first step. Gets hacky quickly when things need to change, like hostname or number of repetitions. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

xargs has a "-P" parameter to run processes in parallel. For example:

```
wget -nv http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux -O- | egrep -o "http://[^[:space:]]*.jpg" | xargs -P 10 -r -n 1 wget -nv
```

Reference:
http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3269/parallel-file-downloading-with-wget

Answer (score 6):

I use [gnu parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) for tasks like this.

Comment: Could you provide an example for calling `curl` with `gnu parallel`?

Comment: Yes, parallel seems very good and it's easy to send the same request 100 times. But an example on how to use parallel with sending 100 different curl requests would make this answer better.

Comment: For example: https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/5914e02df62137e47f32

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `curl` example with `xargs`:

```sh
$ cat URLS.txt | xargs -P 10 -n 1 curl
```

The above example should `curl` each of the URLs in parallel, 10 at a time. The `-n 1` is there so that `xargs` only uses 1 line from the `URLS.txt` file per `curl` execution.

What each of the xargs parameters do:

```sh
$ man xargs

-P maxprocs
             Parallel mode: run at most maxprocs invocations of utility at once.
-n number
             Set the maximum number of arguments taken from standard input for 
             each invocation of utility.  An invocation of utility will use less 
             than number standard input arguments if the number of bytes 
             accumulated (see the -s option) exceeds the specified size or there 
             are fewer than number arguments remaining for the last invocation of 
             utility.  The current default value for number is 5000.
```