# What is the maximum value acceptable for xargs -P argument?

Tags: unix, curl, xargs, man

In [this](https://serverfault.com/a/990298/535264) answer they mention 10

I did man xargs and couldn't find what's the maximum limit.

Is it possible to send 10000 cURL requests per second?
How about 50000 cURL requests per second? I mean all 50000 executing at same time?

Comment: It depends on your hardware and network connection limits.

Comment: Is there any mapping of hardware/network vs. approx -P value? I can use cloud machines.

Comment: the question is what are you trying to curl? if its the same url apache load testing tool can do this without xargs, but remember i already shoot my own server into a DDoS due to forgotten this process in the background ;)

Answer (score 1):

The maximum is implementation-dependent. You can show it by running `xargs --show-limits` (assuming Linux). There may also by (socket) limits by the OS or the user you're running this under.

Comment: I'm getting xargs: illegal option -- -
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr]
             [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs] [-s size]
             [utility [argument ...]]

Comment: Then if you perhaps **provided a little more information about your system** someone could answer your question.

Comment: I use Mac OS...

Comment: I found an example here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/279742/366317 But couldn't figure out which of those 5 sizes is applicable to -P